# How to add Deparment to Azure AD Token

Tags: azure, azureportal, claims

I need to read the Azure Ad user's "Department".

I checked the resource https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims, But it won't help since i can not find the any claim type to read the "Department"

[image]

Comment: Any other concern about this issue? If not, you could accept it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, there is no claim named `Department` in the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#v10-and-v20-optional-claims-set), my workaround is to create the different groups in Azure AD for different departments, add the users in different groups.

Then use the `groups` claim:

[image]

For more information about group claims in the token, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims).